# Solutions to the functional equation $f(1-x) = f(x) + 1 - 2x$

Tags: functional-equations

> Find all solutions to the functional equation $f(1-x) = f(x) + 1 - 2x.$ Source: M&IQ

---

I first tried to use the fact that $1-x$ is cyclic, and that failed. I then tried to apply the fact that when $f(1-x) = f(x),$ we must have $f(x) = ax^2 - ax + b,$ where $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary numbers. How should I move on from here, or is there a better method to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $g(x)=f(x)-x$. Then the given functional equation translates to
\begin{align}
&g(1-x)=g(x)&&\forall x\in\Bbb R\\
\implies &g\left(\frac12+\left(\frac12-x\right)\right)=g\left(\frac12-\left(\frac12-x\right)\right)&&\forall x\in\Bbb R\\
\implies &g\left(\frac12+y\right)=g\left(\frac12-y\right)&&\forall y\in\Bbb R
\end{align}
Take any function symmetric about $\frac12$ $\left(\left(x-\frac12\right)^{2n}, \text{ say}\right)$ and that will correspond to a solution of the given functional equation.

Answer (score 1):

Discussion of techniques to solve functional equations are given e.g. by Evan Chen in ["Introduction to Functional Equations"](https://web.evanchen.cc/handouts/FuncEq-Intro/FuncEq-Intro.pdf) and ["Monsters"](https://web.evanchen.cc/handouts/Monsters/Monsters.pdf). Mostly aimed at Math Olympiad competitors, they are quite accessible.